# Spinning gears animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions

I am not sure what I am missing, but the following animation works in Safari, but does not work in Firefox. Not sure if it's working in IE either.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <i></i><i></i>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/lOBxb.png);
    -webkit-animation: barrelRoll 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: barrelRoll 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: barrelRoll 2s infinite linear;
    animation: barrelRoll 2s infinite linear;
}

i:last-of-type {
    top: 22px;
    left: 56px;
    -webkit-animation-name: invertBarrelRoll;
    -moz-animation-name: invertBarrelRoll;
}

@-webkit-keyframes barrelRoll {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes barrelRoll{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes barrelRoll{
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes barrelRoll{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes invertBarrelRoll {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes invertBarrelRoll{
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes invertBarrelRoll{
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes invertBarrelRoll{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxux7987/2/)

Can anyone suggest which property is missing?

Credits for Original Fiddle:  [Original Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/5JuNw/)

Comment: On an OCD side note, those gears would never work in reality. One of them needs to be turning counter-clockwise.

Comment: good eyes.. you are right.. I will try to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing a property. You need to remove the -webkit- prefix from the @keyframes barrelRoll and @keyframes invertBarrelRoll.

So, this:

```
@keyframes barrelRoll{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Should be:

```
@keyframes barrelRoll{
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

And this:

```
@keyframes invertBarrelRoll{
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Should be:

```
@keyframes invertBarrelRoll{
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```